# AWS EC2 ssh connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, connection

Running into the dreaded ssh connection timed out error. Current situation:

1. inbound rule for port 22, open for all IPs and a separate rule just for myIP.
2. used both public domain name and IP to connect neither works.
3. No, i did not restart ec2 instance. So public domain and IP has not changed
4. Turned off Mcaffee firewall on my PC, still nothing.
5. Used SSHclient extension in chrome, same issue.
6. Tried AWS SSH Java client, fails to connect with no specific error.
7. access on private key file is set to 400, as recommended by AWS. I also tried with 777. Neither works
8. instance status on AWS is good. status check is 2/2.

Output with -vvv flag:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx is address
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxx port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Did `ssh -vvv` give any useful debug output?

Comment: Added -vvv output to post.

Comment: Are there any other services running on this machine you can connect to to verify they work? Can you ping or hit an HTTP endpoint? I don't suppose it's likely, but wondering if the SSH daemon is no longer running.

Comment: No other services on the instance.

Comment: Are you running on a corporate network that has its own outbound firewall rules? Can you connect from a machine that's not running on that network (you don't have to be able to log in, just connect).

Comment: Is it possible that you brought up the instance on a private subnet? IIRC there's nothing in the console that will prevent you from doing that. It will even assign a public IP, but that IP doesn't actually work.

Comment: not on corporate network. this is a straightfwd instance launch through the wizard on the default vpc and subnet. Have done this several times before with no SSH issues. This is the first time this is happening.

Comment: May not help but review the [system log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output).

Comment: There may be a scenario if you or someone from your team had access instance previously, turn on the firewall in EC2 instance, and forgot to allow SSH (port 22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Looks like at some point I deleted the default internet gateway. Created a new IG and associated it with the default VPC and added an entry for it in the route table.

Answer (score -1):

check Network ACLs, Route Tables, SecurityGroup